# change background color of window from data inputed from text field

Tags: javascript, titanium

I am building a 'Carpark Logger' app in Titanium. I have 2 textfields, where users enter what level they are on and what color (area) they are parked in.  When the save button is clicked, I need the background of the next window (saved Location) to change to that color.

I have set a variable of the textField.value and have created a function to change the background color to the text.field value. So far when the  save button is clicked it just changes the background for the savedLocations window to black (or transparent??).

Any ideas on how I can use the text entered in the color textField and save it as the background to savedLocations window.  Here is a snippet of my code:

```
var colourData = colourTextField.value;

saveButton.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    savedLocationsWindow.backgroundcolor = bgColour(colourData);
    carLoggerTabGroup.setActiveTab(savedLocationsTab);
});

function bgColour(color){
    backgroundColor = color;
};
```

Comment: Your `bgColour` function always returns `undefined`. Is that intended behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If would forget about that extra function and just do it like this:

```
saveButton.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    savedLocationsWindow.style.backgroundColor = colourTextField.value;
});
```

Comment: Thank you yes, this solved it. I was trying to make it more complicated than it was. Still learning :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with titanium, but here's a couple of suggestions:

```
function bgColour(colourData) {
    // do some transformations on the color data perhaps?
    // 1. We need to actually return the data:
    return colourData;
}

saveButton.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    // 2. We need to get the value of the text field AFTER the saveButton
    // has been clicked, so this part of code is inside the event listener:
    var colourData = colourTextField.value;

    // 3. Mind the "style" and capital "C" in backgroundColor
    savedLocationsWindow.style.backgroundColor = bgColour(colourData);
    carLoggerTabGroup.setActiveTab(savedLocationsTab);
});
```